# SQL Queries on multiple select statements with dynamic column using ssrs reporting tool

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a project that tests my ability to utilized SSRS reporting tool and sql language skills as I am new to the field. I have attempted get it right but not sure how to approached the requirements. I've tried to do multiple select unions and joins within joins, and select with inner select. So far, nothing works. If anyone could give me a suggestion on how to approach this requirement, it would be quite helpful. My Question is: How do I get it to display 2 sub categories per product if it only has two, or if there is 3 sub cat. displays 3, or if there are more than 3 sub categories, show only 3 sub cat and all else is "Other Sub Cat"? How can I write in my query to show the what THIS looks like: [image: Mockup Detail Output] Below is the project requirements:

- Display 2 sub categories if there are only 2 sub categories per product category.
- Display 3 sub categories if there are only 3 sub categories per product category.
- If there are more than 3 sub categories, then display 3 sub categories, all others will be in a group of "Other Sub Cat".
- The field name is EnglishProductSubcategoryName.

All in all, it should look like this:

Mine, looks like this:

[image: My Detail Output] (Sorry, it was too long to get it all in one screenshot)

This is my dataset just in case anybody want to take a look:

```
--declare @Group nvarchar(20) = null
--declare @SelectedGroup nvarchar(30) = 'North America'
--declare @Year nvarchar(10)
--set @Year = '2008'

declare @Count int = (
    select  count(distinct c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName)
    from
        DimProduct a
        left join DimProductSubcategory c on a.ProductSubcategoryKey =      c.ProductSubcategoryKey
        left join FactInternetSales f on a.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
        left join DimSalesTerritory g on f.SalesTerritoryKey = g.SalesTerritoryKey
        left join DimEmployee h on g.SalesTerritoryKey = h.SalesTerritoryKey
        left join FactSalesQuota i on h.EmployeeKey = i.EmployeeKey
        left join DimProductCategory d on c.ProductCategoryKey = d.ProductCategoryKey
    where 
        g.SalesTerritoryGroup is not null
        and i.SalesAmountQuota is not null
        and i.CalendarYear = @Year
        and c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName is not null
        and g.SalesTerritoryGroup = @SelectedGroup
)

select 
g.SalesTerritoryGroup as 'Group_Breakout'
,g.SalesTerritoryCountry as 'Territory'
,case
    when d.EnglishProductCategoryName is null
        then 'Remaining Categories'
    else d.EnglishProductCategoryName
end as 'Product_Category'
,d.EnglishProductCategoryName
,c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName as 'Sub_Category',
c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
,count(*) as 'Quantity'
,sum(f.SalesAmount - (f.TotalProductCost + f.TaxAmt + f.Freight)) AS 'Sales'

from 
DimProduct a
left join DimProductSubcategory c on a.ProductSubcategoryKey = c.ProductSubcategoryKey
left join
(
     select distinct top 2
        d.EnglishProductCategoryName 
        ,c.ProductCategoryKey
    from
        DimProduct a
        left join DimProductSubcategory c on a.ProductSubcategoryKey = c.ProductSubcategoryKey
        left join FactInternetSales f on a.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
        left join DimSalesTerritory g on f.SalesTerritoryKey = g.SalesTerritoryKey
        left join DimEmployee h on g.SalesTerritoryKey = h.SalesTerritoryKey
        left join FactSalesQuota i on h.EmployeeKey = i.EmployeeKey
        left join DimProductCategory d on c.ProductCategoryKey = d.ProductCategoryKey
    where 
        g.SalesTerritoryGroup is not null
        and i.SalesAmountQuota is not null
        and i.CalendarYear = @Year
        and c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName is not null
        and g.SalesTerritoryGroup = @SelectedGroup 
) d on c.ProductCategoryKey = d.ProductCategoryKey
left join FactInternetSales f on a.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
left join DimSalesTerritory g on f.SalesTerritoryKey = g.SalesTerritoryKey
left join DimEmployee h on g.SalesTerritoryKey = h.SalesTerritoryKey
left join FactSalesQuota i on h.EmployeeKey = i.EmployeeKey

where 
g.SalesTerritoryGroup is not null
and i.SalesAmountQuota is not null
and i.CalendarYear = @Year
and c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName is not null
and g.SalesTerritoryGroup = @SelectedGroup

group by
g.SalesTerritoryGroup
,g.SalesTerritoryCountry
,d.EnglishProductCategoryName
,c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName


 order by
 g.SalesTerritoryGroup
 ,g.SalesTerritoryCountry
 ,d.EnglishProductCategoryName desc
```

Comment: You don't actually have a question here... glancing at the two pictures (pictures are a really really bad idea) they look the same to me.

Comment: So whats your question here???

Comment: My Question is: How do I get it to display 2 sub categories per product if it only has two sub cat., or if there is 3 sub cat. displays 3 sub cats., or if there are more than 3 sub categories, show only 3 sub cat and all else is "Other Sub Cat"? How can I write in my query to show the what it looks like on the first image? Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--declare @Group nvarchar(20) = null
--declare @SelectedGroup nvarchar(30) = 'North America'
--declare @Year nvarchar(10)
--set @Year = '2007';

WITH Details
AS (
    select g.SalesTerritoryGroup AS Group_Breakout
        , g.SalesTerritoryCountry AS Territory
        , d.EnglishProductCategoryName
        , c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
        , count(*) as 'Quantity'
        , sum(f.SalesAmount - (f.TotalProductCost + f.TaxAmt + f.Freight)) AS 'Sales'
    from DimProduct a
    left join DimProductSubcategory c 
    on a.ProductSubcategoryKey = c.ProductSubcategoryKey
    left join FactInternetSales f 
    on a.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
    left join DimSalesTerritory g 
    on f.SalesTerritoryKey = g.SalesTerritoryKey
    left join DimEmployee h 
    on g.SalesTerritoryKey = h.SalesTerritoryKey
    left join FactSalesQuota i 
    on h.EmployeeKey = i.EmployeeKey
    left join DimProductCategory d 
    on c.ProductCategoryKey = d.ProductCategoryKey
    where G.SalesTerritoryGroup is not null
        and i.SalesAmountQuota is not null
        and i.CalendarYear = @Year
        and c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName is not null
        And g.SalesTerritoryGroup = @SelectedGroup 
    Group by g.SalesTerritoryGroup
        , g.SalesTerritoryCountry
        , d.EnglishProductCategoryName
        , c.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
)
, 
ProdCat
as (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 EnglishProductCategoryName
        FROM Details
)

,

SubCat
as (
    SELECT EnglishProductCategoryName
        , EnglishProductSubcategoryName
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT B.EnglishProductCategoryName
            , A.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
            , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.EnglishProductCategoryName  ORDER BY A.EnglishProductSubcategoryName) AS Rank
        FROM Details A
        INNER JOIN ProdCat B
        ON A.EnglishProductCategoryName = B.EnglishProductCategoryName
    ) C
    Where Rank < 4
)

SELECT A.Group_Breakout
    , A.Territory
    , CASE WHEN c.EnglishProductCategoryName IS NULL THEN 'Remaining Categories'
        ELSE c.EnglishProductCategoryName END AS ProductCategory
    , CASE WHEN B.EnglishProductSubcategoryName IS NULL THEN 'Remaining SubCategories'
        ELSE B.EnglishProductSubcategoryName END AS SubCategory
    , Sum(A.Quantity) AS Quantity
    , SUM(A.Sales) AS Sales
FROM Details A
LEFT JOIN SubCat B
ON A.EnglishProductCategoryName =B.EnglishProductCategoryName
    AND A.EnglishProductSubcategoryName = B.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
LEFT JOIN ProdCat C
on A.EnglishProductCategoryName = c.EnglishProductCategoryName
GROUP BY A.Group_Breakout
    , A.Territory
    , CASE WHEN c.EnglishProductCategoryName IS NULL THEN 'Remaining Categories'
        ELSE c.EnglishProductCategoryName END
    , CASE WHEN B.EnglishProductSubcategoryName IS NULL THEN 'Remaining SubCategories'
        ELSE B.EnglishProductSubcategoryName END
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```